# Browser is moving <a> tags outside of <td> tags

Tags: html

Ok, so I am having an issue with HTML. My  tags are being rewritten by the web browser to be outside of the table, which is well outside of their parent class.

This

[image: Example]

Becomes this

[image]

When I build the table by hand using `.appendChild()` in Javascript, I can get it to work. Is there a reason this is happening and maybe a way to get it to work so it's correct without relying on Javascript to build my table?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<tr>` elements can only have `<th> or `<td>` elements as children.

Comment: It's better to run your code in jsfiddle, please don't post image of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML only allows `<td>` and `<th>` elements to be children of `<tr>` elements.

You are writing invalid HTML and hitting error recovery logic. This would be highlighted if you had used [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Put the `<a>` elements inside the cells and apply CSS to make them fill the cell.

Better yet, since it doesn't look like you have tabular data in the first place: Don't use tables for layout. We have CSS for layout and Grid and Flexbox are well supported.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have known that beforehand. Feel stupid for having to ask. Lesson learned.